# jQuery datepicker default date null on postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model that looks like this:

```
public class RegisterResultAdminModel
{
    [DateInThePastValidator(ErrorMessage = "Date needs to be a valid date set in the past.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You need to set Date.")]
    public DateTime DatePlayed { get; set; }
}
```

My validator looks like this:

```
public class DateInThePastValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var date = (DateTime)value;
        if (date > DateTime.UtcNow)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I set DatePlayed to DateTime.Today in my controller's Index method:

```
...
model.DatePlayed = DateTime.Today;
return View(model);
```

In my Index.cshtml I have the following code:

```
@model Web.Models.RegisterResultAdminModel
...
<p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DatePlayed, new { @Value = Model.DatePlayed, id = "datepicker" })</p>
...
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy'});
});
</script>
```

The TextBoxFor is inside a Html.BeginForm.

Ok, getting ready for my problem now.  When the page is shown the date is shown as *09/14/2017 00:00:00*.  Fair enough.  But when I click submit the validator shows value as null (I can see this in the debugger).  However, if I first click on the datepicker and then choose a date it shows as *14-September-2017*.  Now when I click submit the validator accepts the date (the debugger now shows a date) and everything else works fine.

There are plenty of articles on seemingly very similar matters, but I must be missing something obvious.

How can I make this work?

**Edit:** Adding explanation to "shows as null"

Comment: Not related, but remove the pointless `new { @Value = Model.DatePlayed }` and NEVER attempt to override the `value` attribute when using `HtmlHelper` methods.

Comment: Its not really clear what your asking. What do you mean _validator shows value as null_? Your property is `DateTime` and if it were `null` you would be getting another error first. And your posting back a date in a format that does not match your server culture so it could not bind anyway

Comment: model.DatePlayed = DateTime.Today; > model.DatePlayed = DateTime.Now;

Comment: @StephenMuecke Removing ´@Value= Model.DatePlayed´ made the problem go away,.  Now, in debugging, I see a date.  Maybe you should post this as an answer?

Comment: There are a few other statements you made which do not make sense (or I did not understand them). And as a side note, you can use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DatePlayed, "{0:dd-MMMM-yyyy}", new { id = "datepicker" })` to format the initial display. BUt I need some sleep, so feel free to add your own answer.

Comment: @AnimusMiles-Militis Is not DateTime.Today the date of today minus hours and minutes?  And hence DateTime.Now > DateTime.Today?

Comment: Do you need to set the value if you are binding? @Value = Model.DatePlayed

Comment: @AnimusMiles-Militis No, in fact it was wrong and led to other problems.  It was pointed out by StephenMuecke above.  I suggested he post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so that this gets an answer, sicne there is a correct one:

Stephen Muecke correctly pointed out that I should not set `new { @Value = Model.DatePlayed }`.  My date format problems disappeared when I used his second suggestion:

```
Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DatePlayed, "{0:dd-MMMM-yyyy}", new { id = "datepicker" })
```

After this things just work.  So thanks for the help!